# System claims that my iCloud storage is full however it is not

Tags: icloud

As seen in the screen shot My iCloud storage has 1.8TB of free space but my finder says that it is full...

[image: iCloud Setting]

[image: System Preferences]

[image: Finder]

Comment: First shot would be the *'switch it off them on again Hokey Cokey'* ;) Sign out of everything, reboot everything, sign back in.

Comment: Could you also go to https://www.icloud.com/settings/ and tell us if the storage distribution is the same?

Comment: @Lulucmy, ok I added screenshot from iCloud setting also.

Comment: @Tetsujin it seems that the error disappeared in 2 days. This means that apple has a setting propagation error. We need to wait a few days...